# LinkedList as value for Hashtable

Tags: java, hash, hashtable

I've created a Hashtable with a String as key and a LinkedList of Strings as my value. Here is my implementation:

```
 Hashtable <String, LinkedList<String>> table = new Hashtable <String, LinkedList<String>>();
```

What I want to do is sort a file of words and store each sorted word into the hashtable (represents the key) and the store the ORIGINAL word as part of my LinkedList value.

For example, if word is

```
"cat"
 Sorted = "act"
 Store in Hashtable (key : act, value : cat);
```

Now I'm just getting confused how to essentially add to my LinkedList.

This is what I was thinking :

```
 LinkedList <String> temp = table.get(sortedWord) //if null, then nothing in list
 if(temp==null) 
     table.put(sortedWord,temp.add(originalWord));

 This is not working since its not following the library functions but I'm unsure of how I would do this.
```

Comment: If your value is single value so that instead of use LinkeList<String> you can direct use Hashtable <String, String> table = new Hashtable <String, String>();

Comment: But what if the text file contains multiple words that when sorted is the same? That's why I want a LinkedList as the value

Comment: FYI, we usually use `HashMap` instead of `Hashtable`, unless this is a multi-threaded program.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is my solution. The solution is looping through the words, sorting the chars with `Array.sort()`. Checking if the Hashtable is populated with the sorted word, and from there either created the `LinkedList` and adding or adding the element to the already created LinkedList. Not sure why you choose `LinkedList` as your Datastructure.

```
Hashtable <String, LinkedList<String>> table = new Hashtable <String, LinkedList<String>>();

for(String s : new String[]{"cat","dog","mouse", "cat"})
{
     char[] chars = s.toCharArray();
     Arrays.sort(chars);
     String sorted = new String(chars);

     if(table.containsKey(sorted))
     {
         LinkedList<String> list = table.get(sorted);
         list.add(s);
     }
     else
     {
         LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
         list.add(s);
         table.put(sorted, list);
     }
}
```

Which will produce the following Hashtable.

```
{act=[cat, cat], emosu=[mouse], dgo=[dog]}
```

Used this question for Sorting the Chars.

> [Sort a single String in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605891/sort-a-single-string-in-java)

Comment: That was a programming error, due to the wording "Now I'm just getting confused how to essentially add to my LinkedList." I don't think the question is that complicated yet.

Comment: OK, thanks for fixing it.  Please note that the **first** `table.put(sorted,list)` does not accomplish anything, though.  The value in the hash map is already a reference to `list`, and you're just replacing it with itself.  The **second** one is necessary, of course.

Comment: I know, but sometimes makes it more clearer to add the reference for readability.

Comment: Exactly what I did too! Thank you so much! Def. cleared everything up!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
if(!table.containsKey(sorted)) {
     table.put(new LinkedList<String>())
}
table.get(sorted).add(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code:

```
 LinkedList <String> temp = table.get(sortedWord) //if null, then nothing in list
 if(temp==null) 
     table.put(sortedWord,temp.add(originalWord));
```

is that if `temp` is `null`, that means you don't have a `LinkedList`, but your statement is trying to add `originalWord` to a `LinkedList` that doesn't exist.  If `temp` is `null`, then `temp.add` is guaranteed to get a `NullPointerException`.

Using `temp.add` is what you want to do if you **do** have a `LinkedList` (and you don't need another `table.put` when that happens).  If you don't have one, you have to create a new `LinkedList` with one element.  Here's one way:

```
if (temp == null) {
    LinkedList<String> newList = new LinkedList<>(Arrays.asList(originalword));
    table.put(sortedWord, newList);
} else {
    // you have a LinkedList, add the word to it
```

(`Arrays.asList` seems to be the simplest way to create a list with just one element.  It won't be a `LinkedList`, though, so you need an extra constructor call to create the `LinkedList`.)