# Grouping elements from lists into sub lists without duplicates in Java

Tags: java

I am working on 'Grouping Anagrams'. 
Problem statement: Given an array of strings, group anagrams together.

I could group the anagrams but I am not able to avoid the ones which are already grouped. I want to avoid duplicates. An element can only belong to one group. In my code, an element belongs to multiple groups.

Here is my code:

```
       public class GroupAnagrams1 {

           public static void main(String[] args) {
                 String[] input = {"eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat"};
                 List<List<String>> result = groupAnagrams(input);
                 for(List<String> s: result) {
                      System.out.println(" group: ");
                            for(String x:s) {
                                System.out.println(x);
                            }
                   }
      }

      public static List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {

            List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<List<String>>();

            for(int i =0; i < strs.length; i++) {
                Set<String> group = new HashSet<String>();
                   for(int j= i+1; j < strs.length; j++) {
                       if(areAnagrams(strs[i], strs[j])) {
                            group.add(strs[i]);
                            group.add(strs[j]);
                     }
            }

                 if(group.size() > 0) {
                      List<String> aList = new ArrayList<String>(group); 
                      result.add(aList);
                 }
           }
      return result;


    }
```

Here comes the method to check if two string are anagrams.

```
 private static boolean areAnagrams(String str1, String str2) {
         char[] a = str1.toCharArray();
         char[] b = str2.toCharArray();
        int[] count1 = new int[256];
        Arrays.fill(count1, 0);
        int[] count2 = new int[256];
        Arrays.fill(count2, 0);
        for(int i = 0; i < a.length && i < b.length; i++) {
           count1[a[i]]++;
           count2[b[i]]++;
         }
        if(str1.length() != str2.length())
              return false;
        for(int k=0; k < 256; k++) {
              if(count1[k] != count2[k])
                    return false;
        }
        return true;
      }
     }
```

expected output:

```
 group: 
    tea
    ate
    eat
 group: 
    bat
 group: 
    tan
    nat
```

actual output:

```
  group: 
     tea
     ate
     eat
  group: 
     tea
     ate
  group: 
     tan
     nat
```

The order in which the groups are displayed does not matter. The way it is displayed does not matter.

Preference: Please feel free to submit solutions using HashMaps but I prefer to see solutions without using HashMaps and using Java8

Comment: Look at your `if(areAnagrams(strs[i], strs[j]))` statement. You're only adding to a group if there are two matching. You'll never get "bat" in a group alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also would recommend using java Streams for that. Because you don't want that here is another solution:

```
public static List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] strs) {
    List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String str : strs) {
        boolean added = false;
        for (List<String> r : result) {
            if (areAnagrams(str, r.get(0))) {
                r.add(str);
                added = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!added) {
            List<String> aList = new ArrayList<>();
            aList.add(str);
            result.add(aList);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The problem in your solution is that you are moving each iteration one step ahead, so you just generate the not full complete group `["tea", "ate"]` instead of `["bat"]`.

My solution uses a different approach to check if you have a group where the first word is an anagram for the searched word. if not create a new group and move on.

Because I would use Java Streams as I said at the beginning here is my initial solution using a stream:

```
List<List<String>> result = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.stream(words)
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(w -> Stream.of(w.split("")).sorted().collect(Collectors.joining()))).values());
```

To generate the sorted string keys to group the anagrams you can look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605891/9662601) for more solutions.

The result is both my provided solutions will be this:

```
[[eat, tea, ate], [bat], [tan, nat]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have taken a slightly different approach using streams:

```
public class Scratch {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] input = { "eat", "tea", "tan", "ate", "nat", "bat" };

        List<List<String>> result = groupAnagrams(input);

        System.out.println(result);

    }

    private static List<List<String>> groupAnagrams(String[] input) {
        return Arrays.asList(input)
                     // create a list that wraps the array

                     .stream()
                     // stream that list

                     .map(Scratch::sortedToOriginalEntryFor)
                     // map each string we encounter to an entry containing
                     // its sorted characters to the original string

                     .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getKey, Collectors.mapping(Entry::getValue, Collectors.toList())))
                     // create a map whose key is the sorted characters and whose
                     // value is a list of original strings that share the sorted
                     // characters: Map<String, List<String>>

                     .values()
                     // get all the values (the lists of grouped strings)

                     .stream()
                     // stream them

                     .collect(Collectors.toList());
                     // convert to a List<List<String>> per your req
    }

    // create an Entry whose key is a string of the sorted characters of original
    // and whose value is original
    private static Entry<String, String> sortedToOriginalEntryFor(String original) {
        char c[] = original.toCharArray();
        Arrays.sort(c);
        String sorted = new String(c);

        return new SimpleEntry<>(sorted, original);
    }
}
```

This yields:

```
[[eat, tea, ate], [bat], [tan, nat]]
```

If you want to eliminate repeated strings (e.g. if "bat" appears twice in your input) then you can call `toSet()` instead of `toList()` in your `Collectors.groupingBy` call, and change the return type as appropriate.